# Package Manager / Deployment Manager in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, deployment, migration

We are thinking about migrating the SFMC instance to a new instance because of the location of their servers. Can deployment and package managers be used for deployment across separate SFMC instances (Accounts) or only within the same instance (Account)? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Package Manager is not a life-and-shift migration utility.  It has it's limits, so you should plan for manual effort to be part of the process.

Comment: @adamsprigs yes, I am aware it needs thorough planning, thanks 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can use Package Manager for deployments across SFMC instances.
I have just tested this personally.

Also, I have found confirmation in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&type=5), but not sure if they mean by "all instances" different accounts or differents business units linked to the same account...

> You can create packaged solutions containing fully configured
> journeys, automations, content assets, data extensions, attribute
> groups, and more. Keep those items current and version-controlled by
> updating your packaged solutions **across all instances**.

Here is a video that explains an interesting way of using Package Manager across instances:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU42MzkgQiY